# Android: Font Rendering Problems with .ttf >3MB

Tags: android, fonts, rendering

My Android Application needs support for various languages (like Chinese etc.). Most of them are in the DroidSansFallback.ttf file from Ascender.

See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts

On some Android Phones, there is DroidSansFallback.ttf, but with many glyphs missing, e.g. on the NexusOne that is distributed in the USA. There are no Asian Fonts Glyphs at all, mostly only Latin and related characters.

So what to do?

I added to the "assets" my own copy of DroidSansFallback.ttf (I also tried other fonts from other sources) and set it during runtime using the Typeface Class.

With some phones and some .ttf files, the font rendering gets completely screwed up, means the letters are just some dots in one line.

After deeper analysis, the problem boils down to:

1. Small .ttf files seem to always work (<200kB)
2. Large .ttf files don't work at all (>3MB)
3. If the phone has the full DroidSansFallback.ttf installed (which is ~3.5MB), even an 1 or 2MB font screws up. If the phone has only a "lite" Version of DroidSansDallback.ttf installed (which is ~1MB), a 3MB font works fine.

Whats wrong here? Am I missing something? It looks like all installed/used Fonts together cannot be larger than somehwat ~4MB.

Anyone has experienced the same problem? I tried it on NexusOne (2.1), HTC Hero(2.1), SonyEricson Xperia (1.6) and Motorola MileStone(2.0), all show the same behaviour.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: It does look like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of memory on your devices.

All the devices that you listed are quite old. The heap size is around 12MB on those.

Consider using PNGs with chinese text already pre-rendered, if possible.

Comment: The NexusOne has 512MB of RAM (after installing a new kernel).Do you suggest that it is impossible to load a 4MB font on this system?

Comment: I can allocate more than 300MB before the app blows up on the NexusOne. Why do you think the heap is restricted to 12MB?
Using re-rendered PNGs is not an option for my App, I need user-editable text.